# Laravel unique Validation for users

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I have 2 tables, Users & Contacts.
2 Models User & Contact.
The Relationship: User has Many Contact, Contact belongsTo User.

The Migrations:

```
    Schema::create('contacts', function($table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
        $table->string('email', 50);
        $table->string('name', 50);
        $table->timestamps();
    });

    Schema::table('contacts', function($table) {
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
```

How can I validate that user has only one contact with unique email.

```
public static $rules = [
    'email'     =>  "required|email|unique:contacts,email",
    'name'  =>  'min:2|alpha'
];
```

Comment: You have "unique:contacts,email" change this to "unique:contacts.email" this will tell laravel which table the email should be unique.

Comment: Not working, Error that I don't have email in Contacts table - But I have.